# Differentiate behavior between no, close option in message dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, jface

I am using an  open dialog from MessageDialog class

```
boolean confirm = MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL,new Shell(),
                                        "Save Project" has been modified.Save changes?", SWT.NONE)
```

it returns true on yes and false otherwise. it is doing one thing at my end, when i cancel and click on cross behavior it also return false and got close as No option(I have written some steps on false) does. in cacel and cross button it should dispose dialog only, so what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

To distinguish between the 3 response from `QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL` you will have to use the constructor form of `MessageDialog` rather than one of the static method:

```
MessageDialog dialog 
    = new MessageDialog(shell, "title", null, "message", MessageDialog.QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL,
                        new String [] {IDialogConstants.YES_LABEL,
                                       IDialogConstants.NO_LABEL,
                                       IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL}.
                        SWT.NONE);

int response = dialog.open();
```

`response` will be 0 for Yes, 1 for No, and 2 for Cancel.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you explain is correct. As you can see from the [MessageDialog JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/MessageDialog.html), it specifies that the open method will return "true" for OK, and false in all other situations.

If you need different behavior between cancel and close, I would suggest you first create the MessageDialog, an then usethe open() method. This will return an int related to the button pressed by the user to close this dialog, or SWT.DEFAULT (-1) if closed by other means (ESC key, close box, etc.).

Your code would be something like this (Note, I did not get a chance to test this):

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(new Shell(), "Save Project", null, "Project has be modified. Save Changes?", MessageDialog.QUESTION_WITH_CANCEL, new String[]{IDialogConstants.YES_LABEL, IDialogConstants.NO_LABEL, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL}, 0);
int confirm = dialog.open();

if (confirm == SWT.DEFAULT) { // ESC or other close action happened

} else if (confirm == SWT.YES) { // Yes pressed

} else if (confirm == SWT.NO) { // No Pressed

} else if (confirm == SWT.CANCEL) { // Cancel Pressed

}
```